# Dapper unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, dapper

I have EF configured with a `Location` field on my `User` table:

```
 public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
```

However when I query my `User` table with:

```
 user = connection.Query<User>("update [User] set LastOnline = @lastOnline output INSERTED.* where Username = @un",
                        new { lastOnline = DateTime.UtcNow, un = username }).First();
```

I get the following error:

> Message=Error parsing column 122 (Location=POINT (-118.2436849
>   34.0522342) - Object)   Source=Dapper   StackTrace:
>          at Dapper.SqlMapper.ThrowDataException(Exception ex, Int32 index, IDataReader reader, Object value) in
>   d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 4045
>          at Deserialize4650b5f0-d037-49ad-802e-8a9be95e8496(IDataReader )
>          at Dapper.SqlMapper.d__11`1.MoveNext() in d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1572
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>          at Dapper.SqlMapper.Query[T](IDbConnection cnn, String sql, Object param, IDbTransaction transaction, Boolean buffered, Nullable`1
>   commandTimeout, Nullable`1 commandType) in
>   d:\Dev\dapper-dot-net\Dapper NET40\SqlMapper.cs:line 1443
>          at App.Services.BrowseService.GetProfiles(ProfileSearchDto query, String username, Boolean isAdmin) in
>   c:\PROJECTS\App\App-MAIN\App\Services\BrowseService.cs:line 330 
>   InnerException: System.InvalidCastException
>          HResult=-2147467262
>          Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography' to type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography'.

What is causing this?

**Update**

Just for kicks, I tried using EF:

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<User>("bla bla")
```

And I get a different error:

> Message=No mapping exists from object type
>   <>f__AnonymousTypef`2[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String,
>   mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to a known managed provider native
>   type.   Source=System.Data

*goes bald*

**Conclusion**

My app needs to search by radius and currently uses a naive lat/long boxed query.  I was trying to upgrade my implementation to use spatial types, but it looks like my tooling doesn't support this scenario.  Back to being naive I go.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186832/entity-framework-sqlgeography-vs-dbgeography

Comment: @Oluwafemi - I see.  So... How do I make EF and Dapper play nice with the above query?

Comment: EF should handle geography types (but I don't use them at all). Last error seems to be unrelated to geography (but it could be an EF bug when you use geography). Does `User` work fine if you use `context.Users.ToList()`?

Comment: @bubi EF handles it fine if I use `DbGeography` - the issue is Dapper mapping to that type, which is EF-specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dapper doesn't support Entity Framework types *in the core library*, to reduce the number of dependencies. However, it has an extensible type-handler model, and bindings for `DbGeography` are included in the [`Dapper.EntityFramework`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dapper.entityframework) package. Once you have added that, you need to call:

```
Dapper.EntityFramework.Handlers.Register();
```

to ask the add-in to register itself. And then it should work. If you get assembly mismatch exceptions, you should be able to resolve it with assembly binding redirects. This applies in particular to the underlying `SqlGeography` type, where the metadata that SQL Server returns is a different version to the metadata in the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` package. But an assembly-binding redirect works fine.

Comment: Works perfectly.  We're now on `spatial`!  Thanks Marc.

Comment: Further steps and explanation: https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/570