# Exception : No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, geolocation

When I tried to update Geo-location value in database, an exeption occurred.

```
var requestUri = string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", Uri.EscapeDataString(address));

var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
var response = request.GetResponse();
var xdoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

var result = xdoc.Element("GeocodeResponse").Element("result");
var locationElement = result.Element("geometry").Element("location");
var latitude = locationElement.Element("lat");
var longitude = locationElement.Element("lng");
double lat = Double.Parse(latitude.Value);
double lon = Double.Parse(longitude.Value);

var geo = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat, "POINT({0} {1})", lat, lon);

var geoLocation = DbGeography.PointFromText(geo, 4326);
SqlCommand updationCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
updationCommand.CommandText = "Update Communications SET [GeoLocation]=@GeoLoc Where [Id] =@Id";   
updationCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", row.Id);                                        
updationCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeoLoc", geoLocation);
var param2 = updationCommand.CreateParameter();
```

Exeption - "No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography to a known managed provider native type."

Comment: what is your GeoLocation type in db?

Comment: public DbGeography GeoLocation { get; set; }

Comment: try to updationCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GeoLoc", SqlGeography.Parse(geoLocation.AsText()));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SqlGeography instead of DbGeography, because DbGeography is designed to use with EF.

try to

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
p.Name = "@GeoLoc";
p.Value = SqlGeography.Parse(geoLocation.AsText());
p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt;
p.UdtTypeName = "geography";
updationCommand.Parameters.Add(p);
```

More info at this [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23186832/entity-framework-sqlgeography-vs-dbgeography)

Comment: Got another exception "UdtTypeName property must be set for UDT parameters."