# How to insert DbGeography data parameter to database via ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, geospatial, spatial

I am trying to insert `DbGeography` datatype in database via **ado.net** but I am getting error.
Error that I get is:

```
Additional information: No mapping exists from object type System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography to a known managed provider native type.
```

Code that I use:
Entity:

```
public class Position{...
public DbGeography Coordinates { get; set; }
...
```

DB update:

```
position.Coordinates = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", _longitude, _latitude));
...
cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Positions SET [Coordinates] = @Coordinates WHERE PositionId = 1";
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Coordinates", store.Coordinates));
```

What is the way to insert DbGeography type?

Answer (score 2):

It will likely be one of two things.  I haven't tried directly sending DbGeography to SQL through ADO.NET but if you can then you need to set additional properties on the SqlParameter object, as so:

```
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter();
p.Name = "@Coordinates";
p.Value = store.Coordinates;
p.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Udt;
p.UdtTypeName = "geography";
```

If that still doesn't work, then you need to convert the DbGeography instance to SqlGeography.  For help with that, see my previous SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107977/sql-geography-to-dbgeography/16087110#16087110).